# OSGI on Android

Tags: android, osgi, apache-felix

i read so much thinks about OSGI and Android but my question is still unanswered. I working at the moment on a small application for Desktop using basicly equinox as OSGI implementation.  For the common functionality i create an own OSGI-Bundle and using service registry to get the implementation and  the rest is normal pojo.

I would like to ask its possible to run normal OSGI-Bundles on android with apache-felix with?

Im asking because i trying to start apache felix on android but i still getting an exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/felix/main/Main

Big thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use a proper version of Apache-Felix? It is required on Android, to have all jars preliminary converted to dex format. This is the only format Android's Dalvik VM understands, otherwise you end up with this java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: On my desktop implemenation i doesnt use Felix, only some jar from eclipse (as i understand equinox). Bundles that i would like to export to Android have only the org.eclipse.osgi.jar as dependency, nothing else. My idea is/war to create a desktop and android application and the core functionality are seperated from the application logic, that im able to export those bundles to android. 

Yesterday i get running felix on android, but on startup i getting few exception, i will post today the exception here. 

Of course, i creating a dex file from my bundle(s) and adding this to the jar.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [EZDroid](http://www.ezdroid.com/)

(Also note ProSyst have a [android OSGi framework](http://www.prosyst.com/index.php/de/html/content/49/mBS-Mobile-for-Android/), but I'm not sure if it's Felix as you asked)

Some links:

- http://luminis-technologies.com/technologies/ezdroid/
- http://felix.apache.org/site/presentations.data/Apache%20Felix%20on%20Androids.pdf
- http://felix.apache.org/site/presentations.data/OSGi%20on%20Google%20Android%20using%20Apache%20Felix.pdf
- http://lsd.luminis.nl/osgi-on-google-android-using-apache-felix/

Comment: Im copy my felix files to /sdcard/... should this a problem to run felix ?? In the example they copy the file to /data....

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the location of the Felix on Android, there is a significant difference between putting it in /data folder and in /sdcard. Not really familiar with latest ports of Felix for Android, but they might need some permissions which are location based. 
I would suggest to post here part of the Logcat with the exceptions you observe in order to try and offer you a solution for them.
And as you said, since your bundles are not dependent on Felix specific APIs, I would recommend you to check the ProSyst OSGi Runtime for Android. It is available for free on the Android Market:[OSGi Mobile](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.prosyst.mbs.mobile.android). You can put your bundles on the sdcard and then install them via the UI. Hope that helps!